# How to handle multiple asynch downloads

Tags: nsurlconnection

I recently moved my background synch downloads to a view controller and need some advice on how to best handle them asynch.  I have written all the code to show a progressview as the download occurs but as you might have guessed it's not that simple.  Here's how it works.

user sees a tableview with two entires one for each database.  they can press a button to download the database and when the download starts that fires off the asynch URL connection,etc.  This works to a certain extent however it's not that simple.

here's what i want it to do.

1. download the main update URL  (works ok)
2. then download a secondary URL.
3. then apply the first URL content to the sqlite store (code written for that)
4. then apply the 2nd URL content to the sqlite store (code written for that)

(All the while showing progress to the user)

when the downloads were synch it was easy as i just waited for them to finish in order to fire the next activity off but when using the asynch method i'm struggling with how to get them to wait.  Step 3 depends upon step 1 finishing and step 4 depends on step 2 finishing and overall success relies on all finishing.  step 4 needs to wait for step 3 to finish otherwise the database locks will cause a clash.

the second complication is that if the user presses the second button while the first is downloading then steps 3, 4 will clash if they execute at the same time as the first row is accessing the database.

Has anyone done anything similar and if so what was the strategy you used to manage the flow of events.

Also i wanted to wrap this all up in a backgroundTask with ExpirationHandler so it would survive the user pressing the home button... but the delegate methods don't get called when i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is what i did to fix the problem.

1. Created an NSOperationQueue
2. Added the URL operations as NSURLInnvocationOperations
   3.waited until the URL operations were complete (waituntilalloperationsarefinished).

Then set the max concurrent count to 1 which forced the subsequent database operations to execute in series one after the other and thus prevented SQLite from locking it's self out.